# Find and Replace values in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet of product codes. I need to change about 200 of them.

The below code deletes all the data in the cells on the other sheet rather than replacing it with the new product code in the second column.

```vb
Sub Multi_FindReplace()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fndList As Integer
    Dim rplcList As Integer
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim myArray As Variant

    Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet4").ListObjects("Table1")

    Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
    myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
  
    fndList = 1
    rplcList = 2

    For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then
          
                sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
                  LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                  SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        
            End If
        Next sht
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Why transpose the array?  And this looks odd - `For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)` - typically you'd loop over a single dimension of the 2D array...

Comment: Hi Tim. I cannot overstate how much of a novice I am. I have been following an online tutorial to put this together, so in answer I am not sure. How would I alter this to loop over a single dimension of the 2D array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Multi_FindReplace()

    Dim sht As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, x As Long
    Dim fnd As String, rplc As String, tbl As ListObject, data As Variant

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set tbl = wb.Worksheets("Sheet4").ListObjects("Table1")
    data = tbl.DataBodyRange.Value 'no need to transpose
    
    For x = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1) 'loop over data rows
        fnd = data(x, 1)                       'find value
        rplc = data(x, 2)                      'replace value
        If Len(fnd) > 0 And Len(rplc) > 0 Then 'make sure there are a pair of values
            For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
                If sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then
                  
                  sht.Cells.Replace What:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
                      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                      SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
                
                End If
            Next sht
        End If           'have a pair of values
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This is incredible, worked perfectly first time, thank you so much Tim. Amazing.

Comment: Tim Sir, do you have a copy of the working file. Can you please share a onedrive link?

Comment: I don't have a working file - I just edited the posted code.  There's only one Sub though - you can easily add that to any file and try it out.

Comment: Alright Sir, understood Sir.